# How many client IDs should I create for my web application?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

I implemented [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/)  on my web application.

I made a client ID from developer panel and put it in the HTML where Google Sign-in is made.

The client ID is personal but not secret, that means it identifies my app but it does not give power to manipulate data on a backend server (if I get this right, it is the client_secret that let you do stuff on server side).

My web app does not talk to a server of mine, so I don't need to send the ID token to the server in order to validate the logged user.

My question is: what is the association between an app and its client ID?

Must this client ID be *unique* for my app regardless of how many users would log in? Since the client ID should identify my app in front of Google OAuth2 servers *and not logged users*, I thought that

*I don't have to create a client ID for every logging customer because client ID identifies the app and not the customer: this means that I have to create a client ID for every **different** web app using Google Sign-in, **not** for every logging user.*

Could you please confirm my thought above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You thoughts are correct: a client ID identifies the app to Google (operating the authorizaation server), not a user.

Comment: In parallel to my original question, may I ask if my reasoning is still valid if we talk about Service Account and the JSON file associated to Service Account identity? Even in that case, for every Service Account  do I need to create only one JSON file containing the necessary keys, and not for every user impersonated in delegated domain access?